# firebase.transaction in dart

Tags: firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I was trying to use the firebase.transaction function using dart in Angular 2, in javascript I would just be able to do something like

```js
fbRef.transaction(function (currentdata) {
  return currentdata + 1;
});
```

But in dart it seems quite different and asks for a "dynamic" as it's parameter. How should I use this function in dart and what exactly does dynamic mean?

Comment: Do you use a package (which one) or js interop directly ?

Comment: I use the firebase3 dart wrapper.
https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase3